# how to eval php code from mysql table (code contains javascript code)

Tags: javascript, php, eval

i have a script into a varchar field (mysql) and i want to eval only the php part.

eval() function don't execute proprely my php part code, anybody have a suggestion ?

I have tried this but it's not working :

```
    function exec_php($php_string) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/<\?(?:php)?(.*)\?>/m',
        'exec_php_embed',
        $string
    );
}

function exec_php_embed(array $args) {
    if (count($args) != 2) {
        return '';
    }
    list(,$code) = $args;
    ob_start();
    eval($code);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And here is my code (field value in my database)

```
 var quid = <?php echo $quid; ?>;
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        // height: 350,
                        type: bar,
                        stacked: true,
 title: {
                        text: "<?php echo $questions[$dbid]['name']; ?>"
                    },

                    }}
```

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea - what are you *really* trying to achieve, there is going to be a better way of doing it.

Comment: like @CD001 said when i read eval and PHP use in one line i start to wonder that what can go wrong.... You should not execute PHP code from a RDMS as it is very insecure..

Comment: Hi CD001, Raymond, thanks for your feedback, but how can i do a workaround ?

Comment: Well that depends on what your overall goal is. As we mentioned, please explain the full purpose of all this